# Como listar arquivos de uma pasta em firemonkey android?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Tenho que criar uma forma de o usuário procurar um backup gerado pelo meu sistema entre as pastas do dispositivo, para isso pensei em carregar as pastas em um `listview` que conforme é clicado iria entrando nas sub-pastas.

Meu problema é como carregar as pastas? Encontrei alguns exemplos para *Delphi*, mas não consegui fazê-los funcionar em *Firemonkey*.

Comment: Por curiosidade, mas porque o usuário precisaria desse backup?.. em que momento.

Comment: caso o usuario troque de aparelho, ele pode recuperar todos os dados

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui Fazer da seguinte forma

Componentes Listview e Label

```
Uses System.IOUtils
```

No evento Show do Form

```
carregadiretorio(GetSharedDownloadsDir);
```

No evento ItemClickEx do Listview

```
if ListView1.Items[ListView1.ItemIndex].Detail='folder' then
  carregadiretorio(LbFolder.Text+PathDelim+ListView1.Items[ListView1.ItemIndex].Text)
else if ListView1.Items[ListView1.ItemIndex].Detail='voltar' then
  carregadiretorio(copy(ExtractFilePath(LbFolder.text), 0,Length(ExtractFilePath(LbFolder.text))-1));
```

e a procedure que carrega o diretorio

```
procedure carregadiretorio(diretorio: string);
var
  listapastas, listaarquivos: TStringDynArray;
  pasta, arquivo: string;
  LItem: TListViewItem;
begin

    ListView1.Items.Clear;
    LbFolder.Text := diretorio;
    listapastas := TDirectory.GetDirectories(diretorio);
    listaarquivos := TDirectory.GetFiles(diretorio);
    ListView1.BeginUpdate;

    LItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
    LItem.Detail := 'voltar';
    LItem.Text := '..<<';

    for pasta in listapastas do
    begin
      //Carrega as Pastas
      LItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
      LItem.Detail := 'folder';
      LItem.Text := Copy(pasta, Length(ExtractFilePath(pasta))+1, Length(pasta));
    end;

    for arquivo in listaarquivos do
    begin
      //Carrega os Arquivos
      LItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
      LItem.Detail := 'file';
      LItem.Text := ExtractFileName(arquivo);
    end;

    ListView1.EndUpdate;
end;
```

Outra solução segue o link
http://bluexmas.tistory.com/427

Comment: Muito bom, só que tens que adicionar uma classe nova, Androidapi.JNI.Interfaces.pas

Vai me ajudar muito quando eu precisar.

Comment: Eu sugiro substituir `/` por `PathDelim`
 `s:=(LbFolder.Text + PathDelim + ListView1.Items
        [ListView1.ItemIndex].Text);`
pois no windows deu o erro Diretório não encontrado